# Some files are not included during a Tar Gradle task

Tags: gradle, tar

I just observed a very weird behaviour from a Gradle `Tar` task.

Let's take a simple example, 2 files :

```
/tmp/test$ ls
test1.txt  ##test2##
```

Here is a simple `Tar` task :

```
task('testHash', type: Tar) {
    from "/tmp/test"
    extension = 'tar.gz'
    compression = Compression.GZIP
}
```

The file `##test2##` is skipped for some reason, after running `gradle testHash` :

```
/path/to/gradle/project/foo$ tar tvf build/distributions/foo-1.0.tar.gz 
test1.txt
```

It seems to happen when the filename is containing `#` character both at the beginning and the end.

A regular `tar` is working well :

```
/tmp/test$ tar czvf test.tar.gz *
test1.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
##test2##                                                                                                                                                                                                            
/tmp/test$ tar tf test.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                
test1.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                            
##test2##
```

I am using Gradle 4.1. Any explanation ?

Comment: Some time ago gradle had default excludes configured - the same as ant. Maybe this is the case here, however I can't find anything reliable.

Comment: According the Gradle DSL, *If excludes are not provided, then no files will be excluded*

Comment: Yes, I've read that as well. However still remember that I run into similar issue some time ago and these default exclude patterns were to blame.

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes
And we can found `**/#*#`. Not a solution yet but thanks, very good guess ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Opal's comments, I adjusted my searches and found a workaround. There is maybe a cleaner way but this one works for me

```
task('testHash', type: Tar) {
    doFirst {
        org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.defaultExcludes.each {
            DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude it
        }
    }
    from "/tmp/test"
    extension = 'tar.gz'
    compression = Compression.GZIP
}
```

FYI, here are [default excludes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes)

> There are a set of definitions that are excluded by default from all
>   directory-based tasks. As of Ant 1.8.1 they are:
>
> ```
>  **/*~
>  **/#*#
>  **/.#*
>  **/%*%
>  **/._*
>  **/CVS
>  **/CVS/**
>  **/.cvsignore
>  **/SCCS
>  **/SCCS/**
>  **/vssver.scc
>  **/.svn
>  **/.svn/**
>  **/.DS_Store
> ```
>
> Ant 1.8.2 adds the following default excludes:
>
> ```
>  **/.git
>  **/.git/**
>  **/.gitattributes
>  **/.gitignore
>  **/.gitmodules
>  **/.hg
>  **/.hg/**
>  **/.hgignore
>  **/.hgsub
>  **/.hgsubstate
>  **/.hgtags
>  **/.bzr
>  **/.bzr/**
>  **/.bzrignore
> ```